# How can I open multiple XML documents stored in a single list?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

This python list contains multiple XML files in a single LIST.

```
list_xml = ['hello.xml,'hi.xml','08333.xml']
```

I want to parse `Hello.xml` and store the data into another list. Once this is completed, I want to read `hi.xml`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse XML"? Do you want to read the file and then store it as a Python structure (other than string)?

Comment: At first I have to access first variable 'hello.xml   .. do the parsing store the values and close it 

come to second variable i.e "hi.xml " and do the parsing store the values and close it ..

Answer (score 0):

See the pattern of the following code. This should help you.

Also, I'd advise you to go through some fundamentals of programming.

```
list_xml = ['a.xml', 'b.xml', ... ]
out = []
for xml in list_xml:
    # Parse XML here
    # more code
    out.append(parsed_data)
    return
```